# What is the correct way to make a tensor with a dynamic dimension for a Reshape operator in ONNX?

Tags: onnx, onnxruntime

I am trying to add a Reshape node to a BERT onnx model that works with dynamic shapes. The reshape op should reshape a rank 3 tensor to a rank 2. The input to the reshape is of shape [unk__2,unk__3,768] and I need to collapse the first two dynamic dimensions into one and keep the last fixed dimension such as [[unk__2 * unk__3], 768]. How can I specify a dynamic dimension when making a tensor with the onnx helper?

This is my code snippet:

```
# Create a Constant node that contains the target shape
shape_tensor = helper.make_tensor_value_info(name='shape', elem_type=onnx.TensorProto.INT64, shape=(-1,768))

shape_node = helper.make_node(
    'Constant',
    inputs=[],
    outputs=[f'shape_{i}_output'],
    value=shape_tensor,
    name=f'shape_{i}'
)

# Create a Reshape node
reshape_node = helper.make_node(
    'Reshape',
    inputs=[mm_node.input[0], f'shape_{i}_output'],
    outputs=[f'reshaped_output_{i}'],
    name=f'Reshape_{i}'
)
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
raise TypeError(f"'{value}' is not an accepted attribute value.")
TypeError: 'name: "shape"
type {
  tensor_type {
    elem_type: 7
    shape {
      dim {
        dim_value: -1
      }
      dim {
        dim_value: 768
      }
    }
  }
}
' is not an accepted attribute value.
```

The model I am using is the bert-base onnx model and the opset is 18.